# Cormen Wrestler's rivalry BFS

Tags: algorithm, graph, language-agnostic

In Cormen question 22.2.6 we have the wrestler problem. Where it says there are N wrestler i.e N  nodes and r pairs to rivalry i.e. edges and we need to divide the wrestler into good and bad guys such that no 2 good guys are rivals.

Solution given is

Perform as many BFSs as needed to visit all vertices. Assign all wrestlers whose
distance is even to be good guys and all wrestlers whose distance is odd to be bad
guys. Then check each edge to verify that it goes between a good guy and a bad
guy. This solution would take O(n + r ) time for the BFS, O(n) time to designate
each wrestler as a good guy or bad guy, and O(r ) time to check edges, which is
O(n + r ) time overall.

I have few questions about solution

Perform as many BFSs as needed to visit all vertices. -> Starting with different nodes each time? But they will give us the same spanning tree every time?

What about the nodes which are not reachable from BFS

Comment: A graph could be non-connected, that's the reason why you need several BFSs. You start with an unvisited node each time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as @n.m already mentioned. you might be given a graph `G` which might not be connected. For example consider this graph

[image]

You have 2 connected components. If your run BFS (or DFS) from only `node1` you will never discover `node3, node4, node5`. Hence by doing a BFS from each node you would discover all connected components. This also answers you question that doing BFS from every node will not yield the same spanning tree. Hence the complexity being `O(n + e)` for n nodes and e edges.

---

Note - this graph might not be correct for your problem statement as you mentioned N nodes and r pairs i.e. no odd nodes in any connected component. This image was used to explain about connected components.